# Mariadb check constraint with subquerie on current table

Tags: constraints, mariadb

Is it possible to do check constraint with subquery on maria db table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end` datetime NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT C1 CHECK (id not in (select id from tbl as tt where tt.start between start and end or tt.end between start and end)),
   CONSTRAINT C2 CHECK (end>start)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I got error: ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.tbl' doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access an object that doesn't exist (Table 'tbl'), you are trying to create it:

```sql
MariaDB [_]> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [_]> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl` (
    ->   `id` INT NOT NULL,
    ->   `start` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ->   `end` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ->   CONSTRAINT `C1` CHECK (`id` NOT IN
    ->             (SELECT `id`
    ->              FROM `tbl` AS `tt`
    ->              WHERE `tt`.`start` BETWEEN `start` AND `end` OR
    ->                    `tt`.`end` BETWEEN `start` AND `end`)
    ->   ),
    ->   CONSTRAINT `C2` CHECK (`end` > `start`)
    -> );
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table '_.tbl' doesn't exist
```

In case of access to an object that does exist:

```sql
MariaDB [_]> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_TEMP`, `tbl`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_TEMP` (
    ->   `id` INT NOT NULL,
    ->   `start` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ->   `end` DATETIME NOT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl` (
    ->   `id` INT NOT NULL,
    ->   `start` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ->   `end` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ->   CONSTRAINT `C1` CHECK (
    ->     `id` NOT IN (SELECT `id`
    ->                  FROM `tbl_TEMP` AS `tt`
    ->                  WHERE `tt`.`start` BETWEEN `start` AND `end` OR
    ->                        `tt`.`end` BETWEEN `start` AND `end`)
    ->   ),
    ->   CONSTRAINT `C2` CHECK (`end` > `start`)
    -> );
ERROR 1901 (HY000): Function or expression 'select ...'
                    cannot be used in the CHECK clause of `C1`
```

An option that may be useful:

```sql
MariaDB [_]> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl` (
    ->   `id` INT NOT NULL,
    ->   `start` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ->   `end` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ->   CONSTRAINT `C2` CHECK (`end` > `start`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DELIMITER //

MariaDB [_]> CREATE TRIGGER `trg_bi_idduplicate` BEFORE INSERT ON `tbl`
    -> FOR EACH ROW 
    -> BEGIN
    ->       IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL
    ->                  FROM `tbl`
    ->                  WHERE `id` = NEW.`id`) THEN
    ->         SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET
    ->         MYSQL_ERRNO = 31001,
    ->         MESSAGE_TEXT = '`id` DUPLICATE';
    ->       END IF;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DELIMITER ;

MariaDB [_]> INSERT INTO `tbl`
    -> SELECT 1, '2000-01-01 00:00:01', '2000-01-01 00:00:01';
ERROR 4025 (23000): CONSTRAINT `C2` failed for `_`.`tbl`

MariaDB [_]> INSERT INTO `tbl`
    -> SELECT 1, '2000-01-01 00:00:01', '2000-01-01 00:00:02';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [_]> SELECT
    ->   `id`,
    ->   `start`,
    ->   `end`
    -> FROM
    ->   `tbl`;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | start               | end                 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2000-01-01 00:00:01 | 2000-01-01 00:00:02 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> INSERT INTO `tbl`
    -> SELECT 1, '2000-01-01 00:00:01', '2000-01-01 00:00:02';
ERROR 31001 (45000): `id` DUPLICATE

MariaDB [_]> SELECT
    ->   `id`,
    ->   `start`,
    ->   `end`
    -> FROM
    ->   `tbl`;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | start               | end                 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2000-01-01 00:00:01 | 2000-01-01 00:00:02 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```